# Python installation on cygwin

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I am using Windows 8 where I have Python 2.7 installed. In addition I have cygwin installed where I installed also Python 2.7.

I need to install a Python library whose installation on Windows is not supported but it is on Linux so I want to try to use it on Cygwin.

The library has a "configure" script who checks dependencies for many packages and settings and complaints because some python packages are not installed.

But when I try to install them, the system says they are installed. From this, I have concluded that my python windows installation is overlapping my python cygwin installation.

I think that the cygwin is importing in the Path all the windows Path and while the script checking the configuration can find the cygwin installation, when executing from the command-line it is not the case.

Of course, I don't want to remove from the PATH my windows python.

My question is then, what option do I have to work from cygwin only with the cygwin python installed?
As far as I have seen in other questions, usually the problem is the opposite (making cygwin to use windows python, what is problematic and not recommended in some cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the path in your `.profile` then.

So if e.g. your Python is in `C:\Python27`
remove the windows paths to `/cygdrive/c/Python27` in `.profile`

E.g.:

```
$ echo $PATH
 /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:
/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:/bin:/cygdrive/c/Python27:
/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts
```

=>

```
.profile:
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean, and how it will solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, please, can you provide more detail on what should be defined on .profile? PATH variable only? How would this be affected by the automatic import of Path from Windows when cygwin is launched?

Comment: In my case, so that the change takes effect I have had to do the change on .bashrc as explained in http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html. But this has overriden the automatic inheritance of the windows path and solved the problem. The limitation is that any addition to the Windows PATH that I may need on CYGWIN will require a change on the newly defined PATH variable. But, so far, so good. Thanks